# Kafka consumer fails and exits the consumer group abruptly

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Kafka Consumer tries to join the Kafka consumer group but abruptly exits from the consumer group.

Kafka broker logs confirms the member has joined the group.

```
[2021-06-25 19:47:25,612] INFO [GroupCoordinator 1002]: Preparing to rebalance group ABCDSTREAM in state PreparingRebalance with old generation 8 (__consumer_offsets-42) (reason: Adding new member ABCDSTREAM-7480b34a-6e44-4fdc-87ab-71655b9490f0-StreamThread-1-consumer-c75b5014-e853-4b7e-943b-f9873b5e061d with group instanceid None) (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
[2021-06-25 19:47:25,613] INFO [GroupCoordinator 1002]: Stabilized group ABCDSTREAM generation 9 (__consumer_offsets-42) (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
[2021-06-25 19:47:25,701] INFO [GroupCoordinator 1002]: Assignment received from leader for group ABCDSTREAMfor generation 9 (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
```

But just after half a minute the broker logs shows the consumer is leaving the group due to Heartbeat exception.

```
[2021-06-25 19:47:41,859] INFO [GroupCoordinator 1002]: Member ABCDSTREAM-7480b34a-6e44-4fdc-87ab-71655b9490f0-StreamThread-1-consumer-c75b5014-e853-4b7e-943b-f9873b5e061d in group ABCDSTREAM has failed, removing it from the group (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
[2021-06-25 19:47:41,859] INFO [GroupCoordinator 1002]: Preparing to rebalance group ABCDSTREAM in state PreparingRebalance with old generation 9 (__consumer_offsets-42) (reason: removing member ABCDSTREAM-7480b34a-6e44-4fdc-87ab-71655b9490f0-StreamThread-1-consumer-c75b5014-e853-4b7e-943b-f9873b5e061d on heartbeat expiration) (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
[2021-06-25 19:47:41,859] INFO [GroupCoordinator 1002]: Group ABCDSTREAM with generation 10 is now empty (__consumer_offsets-42) (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
```

Following events occurred in the streaming application logs:

> State transition from CREATED to REBALANCING 
> State transition from CREATED to STARTING 
> Subscribing to Topics and Partitions Assignment 
> Finished assignment for group at generation 13 
> Successfully joined group with generation 13 
> State transition from STARTING to PARTITIONS_ASSIGNED

Streaming application logs doesn't show any behaviour due to which it got kicked out of consumer groups in the broker.

Anyone familiar with similar issues? Let me know if there is any further information required.